# C++ universal function caller

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd want to implement a function caller that works just like the `thread` constructor. For example

```
std::thread second (bar,0);
```

will start a thread which calls `bar` with the single argument `0`. I would like to do the same thing, but I do not know how.

For example, given:

```
void myFunc(int a){
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

I would like:

```
int main() {
    caller(myFunc,12);
}
```

to call `myFunc` with the parameter `12`.

Comment: `std::function` and `std::bind` ?

Comment: consider signal/slot?

Comment: For C++17, there will be [`std::invoke()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke), which does exactly that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`std::bind` will make a callable object from any callable object with an arbitrary set of parameters, just as the `thread` constructor does. So just wrap that in a function that calls it:

```
template <typename... Args>
auto caller(Args &&... args) {
    return std::bind(std::forward<Args>(args)...)();
}
```

Note that the `auto` return type requires C++14 or later. For C++11, you'll have to either return `void`, or specify the type:

```
auto caller(Args &&... args) 
    -> decltype(std::bind(std::forward<Args>(args)...)())
```

Comment: can i call a method from an object with this ?

Comment: @MaxianNicu: Yes. For the member function `Class::method()`, and an object `object`, call this with `caller(&Class::method, &object)`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks for specifying BOTH C++11 and C++14.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if this caller function simply wraps up a call to std::bind and returns the same type that std::bind returns, why create the caller function instead of simply using std::bind?

Comment: @scott: this doesn't return the result of bind, it calls it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I see.  I missed the extra parenthesis there at the end.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 7):

If all you want to do is call an arbitrary function with an arbitrary argument, that's just a template on both types:

```
template <typename Function, typename Arg>
void call_with_one(Function&& f, Arg&& arg) {
    f(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
}
```

which you can expand to call with any number of args by making it variadic:

```
template <typename Function, typename... Arg>
void call_with_any(Function f, Arg&&... args) {
    f(std::forward<Arg>(args)...);
}
```

Or really `f` should be a forwarding reference as well:

```
template <typename Function, typename... Arg>
void call_with_any(Function&& f, Arg&&... args) {
    std::forward<Function>(f)(std::forward<Arg>(args)...);
}
```

Note that this will only work with functions and objects that implement `operator()`. If `f` is a pointer-to-member, this will fail - you will have to instead use `std::bind` as [Mike Seymour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29919557/2069064) suggests.

Comment: I suggest taking `f` via forwarding reference too.

Comment: To work "just like the `thread` constructor", it must also work if `f` is a member function pointer.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Would rather link to your answer than copy it :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour Off-topic, but I'm trying to get you some [more badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291520/2069064)

Comment: @Barry would some templated specializations (for pointer-to-member) solve this or I still have to use `std::bind`?

Comment: `std::bind` will work on all types member functions. On the overload front, you'd have provide overloads for the cross product of {`const` or not} x {`volatile` or not} x {no ref, `&`, `&&` qualifiers}. That's a lot of overloads!